# Pygame motion(mechanics) : Why does my player never come back to the ground?

Tags: python, pygame, motion

I already did a jumping system which is working, but i have to do one using mecanics.
At the moment my character never come back to the ground.
Here is my code :

```
def jump(self):
        if self.isJumping == False:
            self.isJumping = True

            self.velx = math.cos(self.alpha) * self.v0
            self.vely = math.sin(self.alpha) * self.v0

        else:  
            self.time += 0.01               
            distX =  self.speed * self.velx * self.time
            distY =  self.speed * self.vely * self.time - (((self.time ** 2) * self.gravity) / 2)

            self.rect.x = round(distX + self.rect.x)
            self.rect.y = round(self.rect.y + distY)
```

And there is a part of the init of my player class:

```
        self.isJumping  = False
        self.v0 = 1
        self.alpha = 5
        self.time = 0
        self.velx = 0
        self.vely = 0
        self.gravity = 1
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Is the player object falling at all?

Comment: I think i found out ! It's beause math.cos() requires a value in radian and i was giving 5 rad when i wanted 5 degree, and i think the player was never fallling because of that

Comment: I had a hunch heh.

Answer (score 0):

The player never comes back on the ground because the expression

> ```py
> distY =  self.speed * self.vely * self.time - (((self.time ** 2) * self.gravity) / 2)
> ```

is a quadratic function of the form "*y = b*x* - a * x^2". *- a * x^2* goes to *-infinity* over time. Since the top left of the PyGame coordinate system is (0, 0), the player always goes higher and higher.